# Two groups of multifile uploads

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload

My situation is this. I have an "edit" page where the user will provide the data for a set of fields. So far so good.

Among the fields, there are two distinct file upload sections (let's say "Technical" and "Fincancial" documents), where I need to provide the functionality to the user to upload multiple files for each section. I have implemented it using the jquery multifile upload plugin, but my problem lies (probably) within the controller code.

I need to distinguish the files in the Request.Files list, to which one of the sections each file is posted. In other words how do I distinguish the "Technical" from the "Financial" docs.

My html code is

```
<input type="file" name="TechnicalFile" id="FinancialFile" class="multi" accept="doc|docx|pdf" />
```

and

```
<input type="file" name="FinancialFile" id="FinancialFile" class="multi" accept="doc|docx|pdf" />
```

but if I use `Request.Files["TechnicalFile"]` I only get the first one of the posted files

**EDIT:**
I also used

```
<input type="file" id="technical" name="technical[]" class="multi" accept="doc|docx|pdf" />
```

in which case when I debug my App I see the list of keys of the posted documents being something like

```
 - [0] ["technical[]"] 
 - [1] ["technical[]"] 
 - [2] ["financial[]"]
```

In this case, if I loop through the files using `foreach(string file in Request.Files)` I get only the first document in the list of each section. If I use a numeric index `for(int i=0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)` I get all the posted files, but I have no indication of which group does each file belong to.

Thanks

*(p.s. I am using jquery-1.4.4 and jquery.multifile 1.47 on ASP.NET MVC3)*

Answer (score 0):

use `FinancialFile[]` instead of `FinancialFile`

Comment: I did, but in my Controller code I just saw a list of "FinancialFile[]" keys, as if "FinancialFile[]" was the key and not an array

Comment: use `foreach` loop to iterate